# sed regex substitution with backreference why not working?

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

I am trying to get the complete filenames with extension (abc.jpg) using sed.

**input.txt**:

```
sfdb/asdjfj/abc.jpg
asdfj/asdfj/abd.gif
sfdb/asdjfj/abc.jpg
sfdb/asdjfj/abc-2.jpg
asdfjk/asdjf/asdf_?/sfdb/asdjfj/abc_12.jpg
asdfj/asdfj/abdasdfj
```

current command:

```
grep ".jpg" input.txt|sed 's:/\([^/]+\.jpg\):\1:gi'
```

the grep is just an example for getting the specified lines (although not necessary here). I already tested my regex to get only the *last '/' + filename + .jpg*: https://www.regex101.com/r/5GTgak/2

**Expected Output**:

```
abc.jpg
abc.jpg
abc-2.jpg
abc_12.jpg
```

But I am still getting the same input file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `sed 's:.*/\([^/]+\.jpg\):\1:gi'`

Comment: You again, are you hunting for just regex questions ;(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still not working, regex should be okay: https://www.regex101.com/r/5GTgak/2

Comment: `/\([^/]+\.jpg\)` will not match any line because `+` is not a meta character with default BRE sed, using `*` would do.. for ex: `sed -n '/\/[^/]*\.jpg/p'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
sed -rn 's/^.*\/([^/]+\.jpg)$/\1/gp' input.txt
```

`-r` option allows extended regular expressions

`/g` - apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first.

`/p` - if the substitution was made, then print the new pattern space.

Comment: can use `s|^.*/([^/]+\.jpg)$|\1|gp` to avoid escaping `/`... also, sed doesn't support non-greedy regex

Comment: @Sundeep, yes, that was *perl* habits, removed *non-gready* stuff

Comment: understandable ;) also, `[^/]` can be replaced with `[^.]` as all `/` are already consumed